# SOAP 1.2 with Axis 2 is not parsed

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

I am writing a server that receives SOAP 1.2 messages. The problem I have is that when I am sending via SOAPui a SOAP 1.1 message, the message is correctly handled but not when it's a SOAP 1.2 message. I use axis2.

Here is my POM dependency:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-saaj</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Here is my main routine to run the server. This is not the actual server (no thread), the purpose is to show the problem.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3400);
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
            conn.bind(socket, params);
            HttpRequest request = conn.receiveRequestHeader();
            if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
                conn.receiveRequestEntity((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request);
                HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request).getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    MessageFactory soapMessageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
                    SOAPMessage soapMessage = soapMessageFactory.createMessage(
                            new MimeHeaders(), entity.getContent());
                    SOAPBody soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

SOAP 1.1 message

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP 1.2 message

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The exception I got with the 1.2 message

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Disallowed element found inside Envelope : {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPPartImpl.<init>(SOAPPartImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPPartImpl.<init>(SOAPPartImpl.java:246)
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.<init>(SOAPMessageImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at lolissimo.xhiara.App.main(App.java:33)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with the official implementation of [SAAJ](https://saaj.dev.java.net/).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when tried to access a spring framework WS.

So, after several intents and fixes to customize the output XML, Finally I was getting this uri `"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"` instead of `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`.

So, chanching the protocol specification from 1.2 to 1.1 solved the problem:

```
MessageFactory.newInstance();
```

instead of:

```
MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
```

In both cases you can still customize your prefixes and namespaces. And, if you are trying to consuming a spring WS do not forget to include the `"soapenv"` prefix in your envelope.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting `WSWS4104E: A SOAP 1.2 Protocol is not supported by SAAJ 1.2.` error while trying to connect to an existing web service with WSDL end point. It was observed that the IBM specific `jar` was not in the class path. The jar file is `com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_8.0.0.jar`.

The variable name is `WAS_V8JAXWS_WEBSERVICES_THINCLIENT`. After adding this variable to Java Build Path I no longer see this error.

Also a link to the other version: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21316678